# Getting program to repeat over input in C

Tags: c, loops

Hi I'm just starting programming in C and am struggling to write a program designed to take a string of integers and then output if the value being checked is smaller than the one before it.  But I cannot get the program to repeat over the data and it seems to only be checking the first value.  I have tried using loops but this further confused me.  Sorry to ask such a basic question.  Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int num;
    int smaller=0;

    printf("Input integers: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num<smaller) {
        printf("*** value %d is smaller than %d \n", num, smaller);
    }
    smaller=num;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... if you want to repeat something you're probably going to need some kind of loop... have you tried following a basic C tutorial on basic language constructs like for/while loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a do-while loop to ask the user for values over and over again until they type something invalid, like `0`:

```
int smaller=0;
int num=0;
do {
    printf("Input an integer (0 to stop): ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num<smaller) {
        printf("*** value %d is smaller than %d \n", num, smaller);
    }
    smaller=num;
} while (num != 0);
```